# How to compute infinite integrals involving products of trigonometric and Bessel functions?

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, bessel-functions

I am trying to evaluate analytically the following infinite integral 
$$
\int_0^\infty q J_1 (qr) \sin \rho q \, \mathrm{d} q \quad   (0<\rho < r) \, .
$$

I was wondering if such an integral is tabulated somewhere or whether there exists a commonly used technique for its evaluation. 
Any help will be welcome.

Thanks.

r

Comment: @tired Doesn't this integral diverge since $J_1(x) \sim \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi x}}\cos(x-3\pi/4)$ for large $x$.

Comment: @Dr.MV you are totally right...good spot..

Comment: The integral $I$ given by 

$$I=\int_0^\infty qJ_1(qr)\sin(\rho q)\,dq$$

diverges since $J_1(x)= \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi x}}\cos(x-3\pi/4)+O\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$ for $x \to \infty$.

Comment: @Dr.MV thanks a lot for your useful hints. The integral is therefore divergent. Greetings,